# Optimize y = x*x in Galois field arithmetic

Tags: c, cryptography, bit-manipulation, low-level

I have this C-code to do multiplications over GF(8):

```
int32_t GaloisMultiply (int32_t a, int32_t b) 
{
    int32_t i;
    int32_t mask = 0x100;
    int32_t y = 0;

    for(i=0;i<8;i++) 
    {
        if(b & mask) 
        {
            y ^= a;
        }
        mask >>= 1;
        y <<= 1;
    }

    if(b & 0x1) 
    {
        y ^= a;
    }

    return(y);
}
```

That's more or less the text-book implementation.

I wonder if I there is a clever optimization for above algorithm if I can assert that a is always b, e.g. I do squaring instead of multiplication. I'm not after a cryptographic use btw. I just want to make use of the fact that x*x in GF(8) interleaves the bits of x with zero bits one by one.

There are already quite clever methods to do the bit interleaving, but since I've found out that x*x in GF(8) does the bit interleaving thing (by accident) I can't stop trying to use it for bit-interleaving optimizations.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table-based? [link](http://www.samiam.org/galois.html)

And when you are limited to x*x, it's a sparse matrix.

Here's another [good paper (and a library)](http://www.cs.utk.edu/~plank/plank/papers/CS-07-593/)

Comment: But I'm sorry, I don't think they are using the squaring effect (bit interleaving) you are talking about explicitly (or whether taking that into account really improves performance).

Comment: The table based method should be way faster whether or not you are squaring

Comment: I'm confused. Couldn't you use a table based approach to bit interleaving 8-bit numbers without knowing a Galois Field from a football stadium? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
int32_t GaloisMultiply( int32_t a ) 
{
  int32_t y = 0;
  int32_t b = a & 0x01ff;

  while ( b ) 
  {
    if ( b & 1 ) 
      y ^= a;

    a <<= 1;
    b >>= 1;
  }
  return y;
}
```

Or if you like:

```
int32_t GaloisMultiply( int32_t a ) 
{
  int32_t y = 0;
  for ( int32_t b = a & 0x01ff; b; b >>= 1 )
  {
    if ( b & 1 ) 
      y ^= a;

    a <<= 1;
  }
  return y;
}
```

The reason that this approach is more efficient than the original code above is primarily because the loop is only performed until all the 'interesting' bits in the argument are consumed as opposed to blindly checking all (9) bits.

A table based approach will be faster though.

Comment: You should add some detail as to why this would be faster

Comment: thanks, after having a look that seems to be as short as it can get.

I'll use tables though. It's faster.

Answer (score 1):

Lookup table is definitely the fastest for polynomial basis galois squaring.  It is also the fastest for multiplication when using GF(8), but the tables get too large for larger fields as used in ECC.  For multiplication in larger fields, the best algorithm is the 'left to right combine' method...(see [http://www.amazon.com/Elliptic-Cryptography-Springer-Professional-Computing/dp/038795273X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/038795273X) algorithm 2.36, page 50).

Comment: If you are using polynomial arithmetic for cryptography, it may be a bad idea to use lookup tables.  At least if you are running on a general purpose computer.   The memory addresses you look up will depend on the values you are calculating with, and therefore the cache sets involved.  There are many, many, papers whereby attackers observe cache misses repeatedly, and thereby manage to break the crypto.  There have even been a few real-world breakins in this manner.  In general, unless you are in an embedded system, avoid lookup tables.

Answer (score 1):

The square `x*x mod r(x)` is simply the superposition of all the weights of the bits *i* in *x* with `w_i = x^{i*2} mod r(x)`.
This can be evaluated with 3 64-bit lookup-tables in parallel.

```
  i0to2 = x & 0b111;
  i3to5 = x & 0b111000;
  i6to7 = x >> 6;
  return (k0to2 >> (i0to2 * 8)) ^ 
         (k3to5 >> i3to5) ^
         (k6to7 >> (i6to7 * 8);
```

This can be reduced to two 3-bit tables, and additional logic knowing the weight for bit 1 == 1 -- that is `result ^= (x & 1)`.
Likewise the weigth for bit 4 == r(x) - x^8 leaving just two 64-bit tables `k1to3, k5to7`.
Here the encoded tables fit 64-bit register with eg the byte 3 (0b11) in k0to2 would correspond to w_0 ^ w_1 == 5 (for all polynomials r(x)).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably write some assembly to do a slightly better job.  However, I'd be pretty surprised if this was the bottleneck in your application; have you done any profiling?  This function doesn't seem like it's worth optimizing.

Comment: It indeed is a bottleneck. If I run the code on a different architecture that does the multiplication in hardware I get up to 30% speed-up.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you are looking for, but here's one minor speedup:

Pass only one argument, if they are guaranteed to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

It might help the compiler a bit to mark "a" and "b" as const. Or unrolling the loop by hand. It would be sad if it helped, though...

Isn't it a patent minefield, by the way ?